# How can I draw an alpha-channel, or clone one texture over the other in Texture Paint mode in Cycles?

Tags: texturing, uv, transparency, texture-painting

I'm looking for the texturing method in Cycles, similar to the texturing [method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=21&v=7679nlyZrK0) in Blender Internal Render.

I have two textures, that have been *Project from View*-ed from two different angles. Now I want to erase some parts of these textures to make one texture seamlessly merged with another.

How can I draw an alpha-channel for the textures in Blender (in Cycles, using Texture Paint mode) or how can I clone one texture over the other one (in Cycles)?

Comment: You may want to see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38399/texture-painting-on-sphere/38414#38414

Answer (score 1):

This is not cycles or Blender internal dependant, this is just texture paint mode. So the principle is the same. You can clone the same way.

You can also "erase alpha" (blend method in the "texture paint mode" tools panel). But this will not "unclone" the original textures.

If you want to erase part of one texture, clone again the other one instead of erasing using alpha.

Answer (score 1):

"Since Cycles is being used here, the actual task of cloning from one slot to another needs to be illustrated. I will try to get something later today once I can get time. Also, a node group showing how to get the same blend of the two image textures will be needed."
edit: Here is a screen grab of a simple set up showing a cycles node tree using two different UV mappings and images, and one has been painted with 'erase alpha' to reveal the other, and then alsoo the clone tool was used to clone from the base image slot to the top slot red image. The image that is being painted to erase alpha has its alpha plugged into the mix factor of the color mix node. The effect of the alpha erase is seen in the 3d view in Material draw mode, as well as in the UV Image Editor where the transparency has appeared. Also, you will see there the bit that was cloned from the other slot image texture.[image: example of clone tool and erase alpha texture paint in cycles]